# JsonLoader throws error in pig

Tags: json, apache-pig

I am unable to decode this simple json , i dont know what i am doing wrong.
please help me in this pig script.

I have to decode the below data in json format.

## 3.json

```
{
"id": 6668,
"source_name": "National Stock Exchange of India",
"source_code": "NSE"
}
```

## and my pig script is

```
a = LOAD '3.json' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader ('id:int, source_name:chararray, source_code:chararray');
dump a;
```

## the error i get is given below:

```
2015-07-23 13:40:08,715 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task: attempt_local1664361500_0001_m_000000_0
2015-07-23 13:40:08,775 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2015-07-23 13:40:08,780 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Processing split: Number of splits :1
Total Length = 88
Input split[0]:
   Length = 88
  Locations:

-----------------------

2015-07-23 13:40:08,793 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader - Current split being processed file:/home/hariprasad.sudo/3.json:0+88
2015-07-23 13:40:08,844 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: a[1,4] C:  R:
2015-07-23 13:40:08,861 [Thread-5] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map task executor complete.
2015-07-23 13:40:08,867 [Thread-5] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1664361500_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@61a79110; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@61a79110; line: 1, column: 3]
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@61a79110; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@61a79110; line: 1, column: 3]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1291)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:318)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase._handleEOF(JsonParserBase.java:354)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._skipWSOrEnd(Utf8StreamParser.java:1841)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:275)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader.readField(JsonLoader.java:180)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader.getNext(JsonLoader.java:164)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-23 13:40:09,179 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2015-07-23 13:40:09,179 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local1664361500_0001 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2015-07-23 13:40:09,179 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-07-23 13:40:09,180 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-07-23 13:40:09,180 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Detected Local mode. Stats reported below may be incomplete
2015-07-23 13:40:09,181 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.3.0-cdh5.1.3  0.12.0-cdh5.1.3 hariprasad.sudo 2015-07-23 13:40:07     2015-07-23 13:40:09     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1664361500_0001        a       MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed!    file:/tmp/temp-65649055/tmp1240506051,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "file:///home/hariprasad.sudo/3.json"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp-65649055/tmp1240506051"

Job DAG:
job_local1664361500_0001


2015-07-23 13:40:09,181 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2015-07-23 13:40:09,186 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias a
Details at logfile: /home/hariprasad.sudo/pig_1437673203961.log
grunt> 2015-07-23 13:40:14,754 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map > map
```

Please help me in understanding what is wrong.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the compact version of json in 3.json. We can use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org for the same.

**3.json**

```
{"id":6668,"source_name":"National Stock Exchange of India","source_code":"NSE"}
```

with this we are able to dump the data :

```
(6668,National Stock Exchange of India,NSE)
```

Ref : [Error from Json Loader in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130021/error-from-json-loader-in-pig) where similar issue is discussed.

**Extract from the above ref. link :**

Pig doesn't usually like "human readable" json. Get rid of the spaces and/or indentations, and you're good.

Comment: Thank you Murali , now i can understand :-)